# React cannot detect URL params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

You can see in the picture, it might be a React Router DOM 4 problem,
in the documentation it uses functional component but this is class based component, and I cant find the solution:

product page code for getting the product id from url params:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.fetchProduct(id);
}
render() {
    const {product} = this.props;
    return _.map(product, prod => {


        return (

            <div className="container">
                <section className="pt-15 pb-15">
                    <div id="col_back">

                        <header className="block">
                            <h1 className="fs-30 fw-300 mb-0">{prod.brand}</h1>

                        </header>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            )}
    )}
}



function mapStateToProps({products}, ownProps) {
    return {product: products[ownProps.match.params.id]};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchProduct})(ProductDetail);
```

the route code:

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/cart" component={Cart}/>
                <Route path="/products" component={Products}/>
                <Route path="/:id" component={ProductPage}/>
                <Route path="/*" component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

[cannot read property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3vjS.png)

Comment: Please edit your post and include the whole `Router` relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your connect HOC with `withRouter` and you will be able to access the params,

```
componentDidMount() {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.fetchProduct(id);
}
render() {
    const {product} = this.props;
    return _.map(product, prod => {


        return (

            <div className="container">
                <section className="pt-15 pb-15">
                    <div id="col_back">

                        <header className="block">
                            <h1 className="fs-30 fw-300 mb-0">{prod.brand}</h1>

                        </header>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            )}
    )}
}



function mapStateToProps({products}, ownProps) {
    return {product: products[ownProps.match.params.id]};
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchProduct})(ProductDetail));
```

Comment: wow man thanks but I think there is no need for () beside withRouter